# Is it possible in AvalonDock to programatically change DockableContent state to floating?

Tags: c#, avalondock

In my application I'm loading windows from 'plugins', so my app doesn't know them until runtime. I'm creating DockableContent for each plugin and sets it's Content to Control returned by plugin. Each plugin tells, if it's window should be initially docked or floating, user can change it later.

So I have an instance of DockableContent and I want to change it to FloatingWindow programatically. Changing content.DockableStyle to DockableStyle.Floating isn't enough, what else I have to do?

EDIT:
I've found it. I've added DockableContent to DockPane and called DockableContent.ShowAsFloatingWindow()... 
IMHO AvalonDock needs better documentation...

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer and then accept it, it'll just make it easier for anyone stumbling across this to see your solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it. I've added DockableContent to DockPane and called DockableContent.ShowAsFloatingWindow()... 
IMHO AvalonDock needs better documentation...